# I wanted to delete the open?

Tags: javascript

I did some sample articles, and are added to my case, and then want to delete. The delete does not work! Does anyone know why this happens?

http://jsfiddle.net/8YP94/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**click(callback)** function change to **live("click", callback)** ok.

so; If you want to know what is the live function see

Sample and results:
http://jsfiddle.net/8YP94/2/

http://api.jquery.com/live/

take it easy.

Comment: `jQuery.live()` is deprecated. Use `jQuery.on()` instead.

Comment: @bhb yes, but it can be used. can be used for a very simple process.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason:** `.delete` was not there when DOM was loaded, it is added later in the DOM , so we call it future node, so use `.live`

```
$(".delete").live('click', function() {
```

for **jQuery 1.8** you can use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete',function() {
```

[`live DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/8YP94/3/)